# Pandas series returning wrong index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm very confused, I'm getting a `KeyError` whenever I execute this piece of code:

```
for k, v in df['crew_data'].items():
        if v == 'xxx':
            df = df.drop([k])
    return df
```

If the keys are being extracted for the same `for` loop, then why are they non-existant?

Comment: can you put a sample data? Also can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Just a side note... you should do this as: `df = df[df['crew_data'] != 'xxx']`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're not looping over what you think you are. I think you're looking for `df.iterrows()` like so:

```
for k, v in df.iterrows():
    if v['crew_data'] == 'xxx':
            df = df.drop([k])
    return df
```

Try printing out `k` and `v` in your loop and see what they are doing, then do the same in mine.

Comment: This should work, but the answer that @Jon Clements gave is a bit more efficient. Thanks anyways